# Evaluating recommenders - unable to recommend in x cases

Tags: mahout

I'm exploring some of the code examples in Mahout in Action in more detail. I have built a small test that computes the RMS of various algorithms applied to my data.

Of course, multiple parameters impact the RMS, but I don't understand the "unable to recommend in ... cases" message that is generated while running an evaluation.

Looking at StatsCallable.java, this is generated when an evaluator encounters a NaN response; Perhaps not enough data in the training set or the user's prefs to provide a recommendation.

It seems like the RMS score isn't impacted by a very large set of "unable to recommend" cases. Is that assumption correct? Should I be evaluating my algorithm not only on RMS but also the ratio of "unable to recommend" cases versus my overall training set?

I'd appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this essentially means there was no data at all on which to base an estimate. That's generally a symptom of data sparseness. It should be rare, and happen only for users with data that's very small or disconnected from others'.

I personally think it's not such a big deal unless it's a really significant percentage (20%+?) I'd worry more if you couldn't generate any recs at all for many users.

Comment: Sean - I wanted to reply back and say thanks for the reply.  I ended up running a battery of tests and found that for my data set, Pearson fared worst and Log Likelihood was the best user-based recommendation.  Generally, 10% of my data fell into the "unable to recommend" category, but for Pearson it was more like 20%.  Either way, to compare apples-to-apples, I ended up factoring in the unable-to-recommend data into my RMS score to fairly compare all recommenders.

Comment: The Pearson correlation is undefined in corner cases, like when two people overlap in just 1 item. On sparse data, that's not uncommon. Log-likelihood is at least defined in these cases. (It's a better default.) The result does not surprise me.