# Mahout evaluation - unable to recommend in x cases

Tags: mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I am trying to evaluate the recommender algorithms on my data set which probably is sparse, and I have only 341 items for around 20 000 users. I just want to evaluate all of the similarity algorithms. I tried almost all user-based recommendations, and for all of them I am getting this INFO from the evaluator, no matter which one, (`AverageAbsoluteDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator` or Root mean-square scoring Evaluator) which is *Unable to recommend in xXXX cases*.  However the final output still have some result. Here is the output of my evaluator:

```
3/06/17 14:11:35 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Beginning evaluation using 0.7 of org.apache.mahout.cf.taste.impl.model.jdbc.PostgreSQLJDBCDataModel@44303e7b
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO model.GenericDataModel: Processed 10000 users
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO model.GenericDataModel: Processed 20000 users
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO model.GenericDataModel: Processed 20530 users
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Beginning evaluation of 11240 users
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Starting timing of 11240 tasks in 4 threads
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 4ms
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 57MB / 101MB
13/06/17 14:15:17 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 3 cases
13/06/17 14:15:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 4ms
13/06/17 14:15:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 48MB / 99MB
13/06/17 14:15:19 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 882 cases
13/06/17 14:15:20 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:20 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 33MB / 109MB
13/06/17 14:15:20 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 1787 cases
13/06/17 14:15:22 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:22 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 41MB / 86MB
13/06/17 14:15:22 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 2687 cases
13/06/17 14:15:23 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:23 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 38MB / 98MB
13/06/17 14:15:23 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 3569 cases
13/06/17 14:15:24 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:24 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 28MB / 93MB
13/06/17 14:15:24 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 4465 cases
13/06/17 14:15:26 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:26 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 41MB / 88MB
13/06/17 14:15:26 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 5420 cases
13/06/17 14:15:27 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:27 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 45MB / 90MB
13/06/17 14:15:27 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 6317 cases
13/06/17 14:15:28 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:28 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 46MB / 103MB
13/06/17 14:15:28 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 7220 cases
13/06/17 14:15:30 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:30 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 72MB / 102MB
13/06/17 14:15:30 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 8145 cases
13/06/17 14:15:31 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:31 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 67MB / 99MB
13/06/17 14:15:31 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 9084 cases
13/06/17 14:15:33 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Average time per recommendation: 5ms
13/06/17 14:15:33 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Approximate memory used: 31MB / 83MB
13/06/17 14:15:33 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Unable to recommend in 9982 cases
13/06/17 14:15:33 INFO eval.AbstractDifferenceRecommenderEvaluator: Evaluation result: 1.643042326271061
```

I don't understand the numbers, why they show so many times, and is this unable to recommend in xxx cases bigger then 20% of all my data? Does it mean that for one user it can't recommend in 3 cases, and for other in 9892?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluating recommenders - unable to recommend in x cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10355031/evaluating-recommenders-unable-to-recommend-in-x-cases)

Comment: It may be. I asked there the same question as here, but it got deleted from the admins. I am not sure why there is so much info and the numbers in _Unable to recommend in XXX cases_ increases each time. Does it mean that the similarity algorithm is not suitable for my dataset?

Comment: Possible reasons: data too sparse, too little data, using a similarity metric that isn't defined on very sparse data, using too much test and too little training data

Comment: did you manged to figure out the problem ?

Comment: It was so long time ago, but I think if you have the same problem you should try the suggestions from @SeanOwen. I think for me was the data was too sparse.